# "LIST object not callable ERROR

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, pycharm, typeerror

[image]

Help me to rectify my code why this error occurs:

> "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable"

Answer (score 0):

`key` is meant to be a callable (typically a function). You have provided something in square brackets, which is a list. A list is not callable.

Try:

```
min(input, key=find_count_vowel)
```

`find_count_vowel` is a function so that's all you're meant to pass. Don't call the function before passing it.

However the key function is only meant to take in a single element of the list for which you want to find the minimum (the `min` function will call the `key` function once for each element in this list) so you will also need to fix your definition of `find_count_vowel`. It should take in a single word and and return the number of vowels in that word, not take in a list and return a list.